# Performance difference using IF function vs AND in MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, performance, if-statement, where-clause

I am writing a query that should find rows where the `created` column is older than x hours ago. However, "x" will be variable depending on another column value.

I have two ways of writing this and was wondering if there will be any performance differences between them:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    created > NOW() - INTERVAL IF(column1 > 500, 365, 750) DAY
```

vs

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    column1 > 500 
        AND created > NOW() - INTERVAL 365 DAY
    OR
    column1 <= 500 
        AND created > NOW() - INTERVAL 750 DAY
```

Comment: Both queries will incur a table-scan.

Comment: In general, MySQL is poor at optimizing OR conditions. I you have an index on `column1`, it would be best to use separate queries that you combine with `UNION`.

Comment: Since the `OR` cases do not overlay, use `UNION ALL` (instead of the slower, default, `UNION DISTINCT`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index on `column1` and use `UNION` to combine the two conditions.

Even better might be to have a composite index on `(column1, created)`, so both parts of the condition can be done entirely within the index.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column1 > 500 AND created > NOW() - INTERVAL 365 DAY

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column1 <= 500 AND created > NOW() - INTERVAL 750 DAY
```

Comment: That makes perfectly sense. Thank you Barmar!